# Panel vs GroupBox in a Windows Forms application

Tags: .net, panel, groupbox

Aren't both doing the same thing? How is each different from the other in case of a Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Apart from the appearance, Panel is Scrollable whereas GroupBox isn't, and GroupBox has a caption, whereas a Panel doesn't.

Comment: That's pretty much it alright, they're both containers, and both function the same without borders, captions or scrollbars

Answer (score 4):

> Apart from the appearance, Panel is Scrollable whereas GroupBox isn't, and GroupBox has a caption, whereas a Panel doesn't.

Panel is scrollable, GroupBox is not.
Panel allows drop, GroupBox don't.
GroupBox always have property TabStop enabled, in Panel you can choose.